# Why does </span> add a new array position entry?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my placement of the first /span (_S) in the defFD variable is creating a new position in the array. I want to set one color for the portion dayname[i] and another after the span variable ND. But when I put the /span (_S) after the dayname section (before ND) in that position it splits the dayname into array position [0] and the rest into pos [1]. Why?

The result of the above code looks like this for the Day forecast: defFD = ["Wednesday Jan 5-", "A foggy day with a high of 47º. Hum 47%. Winds ESE at 10mph. Prec 10% chance.] I need there to be a single long string at position [0] without being split after "Wednesday Jan 5". I've come at this from several angles. Need fellow pros to help.

````
    // STYLING VARIABLES for EXTRA DATA
    var DN = '<span style= color:' + ( (where == "day") ? font_color_night : font_color_day ) + '>'; //Day-Night Color Swap
    var ND = '<span style= color:' + ( (where == "day") ? font_color_day : font_color_night ) + '>'; //Night-Day Color Swap
    var _S = "</span>"; //remove styling
    // BUILD WEATHER DATA
    var defFD = [];
    for (i=0; i < (ForecastDays)+1; i++) {
        defFD[i] = DN + obj.dayname[i] + " " + Suffix(dates[i]) + "- " + _S
        + ND + convertTxtDay(obj.day_desc[i]) + ((obj.code[i] == 24 && obj.day_desc[i].indexOf("wind") == -1) ? " and windy " : " ")
        + "with a high of " + obj.high[i] + "&#176;" + Unit + ". "
        + "Hum " + obj.day_humidity[i] + "%. "
        + "Winds " + obj.day_cardinal[i] + " at " + obj.day_speed[i] + windspeedunit + ". "
        + ((obj.pop[i] != 0) ? "Prec." + obj.pop[i]+ "% chance." : "") + _S + "<P>"
        ;
        defFN[i] = DN + obj.dayname[i] + nighttext + "- " + _S
        + ND + convertTxtNight(obj.ndesc[i]) + ((obj.code[i] == 24 && obj.ndesc[i].indexOf("wind") == -1) ? " and windy " : " ")
        + "with a low of " + obj.low[i] + "&#176;" + Unit + ". "
        + "Hum " + obj.nhum[i] + "%. "
        + "Winds " + obj.ncard[i] + " at " + obj.nspeed[i] + windspeedunit + ". "
        + ((obj.npop[i] != 0) ? "Prec." + obj.npop[i]+ "% chance." : "") + _S + "<P>"
        ;

        if (DayOnly == false) { defForecast.push(defFD[i], defFN[i]); } //move day & night alternating into 1 array
        else { defForecast.push(defFD[i]); }
    } ```
````

Comment: can you provide more source code so that we can run the example and try to reproduce?

Comment: Are these variable names deliberately obfuscated? That's not helping our understanding.

Comment: Let me give you the whole section... Sorry.. Editing original post now.

Comment: `.pop[i]` is going to be `undefined`... always. You don't actually call the method, but access a non existing property of the function object. Why not use the debugging tools to inspect your variables and step through the code?

Comment: Also, try encapsulating the assignment in parentheses: breaking addition operators on multiple lines may cause the JS to interpret it in unexpected ways

Comment: pop is a variable defined in my code earlier @trincot - it works perfectly. Don't believe that is causing my issue. Debugging tools turned up no errors.

Comment: @tadman Do you mean you need to see the variables defined? They're not particularly obfuscated.

Comment: It just helps us when we don't need a decoder ring to find out what `DN` means. It should be pretty obvious from the name what that means. This code is exceptionally cluttered and because of that hard to follow. The variable names aren't helping at all.

Comment: "pop is a variable defined in my code earlier": that is why we ask you to provide enough code to reproduce the issue on our side. We cannot know which variables have which values without seeing the relevant code for it. NB: calling a property `pop` is evil.

Comment: Helpful input. You can see this is my first question here.. I now know you need a simplified version of what I'm attempting to do .. and wanting to be able to run the code itself on your end.. I will re-format the question a little later and take out a lot of the 'clutter' and provide all the variables needed. Though I did specifically list what DN and ND are. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing the quotation marks around your style attributes:

```
var DN = '<span style="color:' + ( (where == "day") ? font_color_night : font_color_day ) + '">';
var ND = '<span style="color:' + ( (where == "day") ? font_color_day : font_color_night ) + '">';
```

Comment: Single quotes or double quotes are interchangable for text in javascript to my knowledge.

Comment: I'm referring to the necessary quotation marks around your `style` values, which are absent.

Comment: Please show me how it should be written? Currently that style applies perfectly in my code.. But perhaps an error in syntax could be causing the the other issue. Please post what you believe those two lines should look like? No error is thrown in debuggers.

Comment: Without the ternary expression it would be 
`var DN = '<span style="color:#FFFFFF">'; var ND = '<span style="color:#000000">';` ... I'm just adding a ternary to replace the color codes. Isn't adding a ternary between a pair of single quotes correct syntax?

Comment: My post already shows your variables defined with double quotes added around your `style` attributes. The ternary portion is fine.

Comment: Aha! Ed... I now see what you did.. In my original.. The double quote before color was only a single.. I thought you just copied and pasted.. Thank you very much!.. But it doesn't solve my original issue. My own answer above does.. But I don't know why I can't /span in the middle of a variable definition without it causing a new array position to be added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what solves my issue is to simply add the /span's both at the end and not the middle.. Though no idea why I can't add an /span in the middle of the variable declaration without it adding a new array position.

```
    var DN = '<span style="color:' + ( (where == "day") ? font_color_night : font_color_day ) + '">';
    var ND = '<span style="color:' + ( (where == "day") ? font_color_day : font_color_night ) + '">';
    var _S = "</span>"; //remove styling

    defFD[i] = DN + (other variables here) +
    ND + (other variables here) +
    _S + _S;
```